# Return a Hourly minimum count of column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have written below code  and I want to return a pqpageId, date and hour on which it has a minimum count.
Thanks in advance.

code :

```
WITH CTE AS (
                  SELECT PQIM.PQPageID
                        ,PQIM.PageURL as PageDescription
                        ,CONVERT(Date,NCPI.RequestDateTime) AS [Date]
                        ,DATEPART(HOUR,NCPI.RequestDateTIme) AS [HOUR]
                        ,ISNULL (COUNT(NCPI.PQPageID),0)AS HourlyPQPageIdCount

                    FROM dbo.NewCarPurchaseInquiries AS NCPI WITH (NOLOCK) 
                    RIGHT JOIN  dbo.PQPageIds_MasterTblFrom3rdNov2015 AS PQIM  WITH (NOLOCK)
                                ON PQIM.PQPageID = NCPI.PQPageId
                                --WHERE NCPI.RequestDateTime between dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()) and getdate()   
                                WHERE CONVERT(DATE,NCPI.RequestDateTime) >= '2015-11-04'
                                AND DATEPART(hour,NCPI.RequestDateTime) between 8 and 23
                        GROUP BY PQIM.PQPageId,CONVERT(Date,NCPI.RequestDateTime), DATEPART(HOUR,NCPI.RequestDateTIme),PQIM.PageURL 
                    )

    SELECT  CT.PQPageId , CT.Date ,CT.HOUR, MIN( CT.HourlyPQPageIdCount)AS MINCOUNT          
    FROM CTE CT WITH (NOLOCK)
    GROUP BY  CT.PQPageId , CT.Date ,HourlyPQPageIdCount,CT.HOUR
    ORDER BY MINCOUNT,CT.[HOUR],CT.[Date], PQPageID asc  

Output : 

PQPageId    Date    HOUR    MINCOUNT
1   04-11-2015  8   2359

1   05-11-2015  8   2332

1   06-11-2015  8   2008

1   07-11-2015  8   1964

1   08-11-2015  8   2139

1   09-11-2015  8   54


2   04-11-2015  9   10

2   11-11-2015  9   56
```

**But I am expecting**

PQPageId    || Date     || HOUR || MINCOUNT

1             09-11-2015    8   54

2             04-11-2015    9   10

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please make sure your question actually contains a question.  Explain the logic your query is trying to implement instead of expecting people to infer it from the expected and actual outputs.  The more information you provide the better your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
WITH CTE AS (...)
SELECT PQPageId, Date, HOUR, HourlyPQPageIdCount AS MINCOUNT
FROM (
   SELECT  PQPageId, Date, HOUR, HourlyPQPageIdCount
           RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY HOUR ORDER BY HourlyPQPageIdCount) AS r
   FROM CTE WITH (NOLOCK) ) A
WHERE r = 1
```